# Redo a merge before previous commit after pushing both the merge and commit to origin?

Tags: git, merge

I have merged 'develop' into my 'feature' branch, which produced some issues which I then fixed and commited ('merge fixes'). Both the merge and 'merge fixes' were then pushed to origin. Afterwards, it appears the merge was not satificatory in the first place and caused some issues (in hind-sight it looks like maybe the merge strategies were not what I wanted) and has left my code in a working, but buggy state. So I would like to revert back to before the merge and attempt the merge again. It was a massive merge so it's not enitrely practical to revert the changes manually.

I have read "git revert" would be what I want (to revert the 'merge fixes'), and specifically "git revert -m" to revert the merge itself, however I have also read that this means I cannot merge 'develop' back into my 'feature' branch in the future, only changes made since the original merge. Did I read this correctly? And if so what I can do attempt this merge again?

Essentially I would like to go back to the commit before the merge and attempt the merge again while preserving history. Would it be easier to branch from before the merge (say 'feature2') and do it again?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your history is probably more complicated, but let’s use the history below as a representative.

```
*   9a905c0 (HEAD -> feature) Merge branch 'develop' into feature
|\
| * 286195b (develop) Change 3
| * 39fc565 Change 2
* | bff23af Feature change 2
* | 8929388 Feature change 1
|/
* 5229c14 Change 1
```

You want a new commit whose tree (that is, the versions of all files being tracked) matches “Feature change 2” (SHA1 object name bff23af in my history). The plumbing command [`git commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) will do exactly this. It may also be your first peek behind the curtain and first step toward Git wizardry.

To go back at least momentarily to your BFF, run

```
git commit-tree -p 9a905c0 -m 'Undo incorrect merge; revert to bff23af' bff23af^{tree}
```

Breaking this down one piece at a time:

- the `-p` option gives the SHA1 object name for the commit you want to be the parent of your new commit. In this case, we want the parent to be the flawed merge. (Note that you can make a merge commit with multiple `-p <sha1>` options.)
- `-m` introduces a commit message as with several other Git commands
- `<sha1>^{tree}` identifies the tree object associated with the commit *sha1*. You also want that to be the tree associated with your new commit, effectively going back to the state before you attempted the merge.

Plumbing commands are designed to be run by other programs and can be slightly cumbersome for a user to run. The output of `git commit-tree` in my repository was

```
16c6ef49aa4f3ea865d76e78b5306c52b14b1f0b
```

That is the SHA1 object name of the new commit that Git just created. To bring it into the feature branch, run

```
git merge --ff-only 16c6ef49aa4f3ea865d76e78b5306c52b14b1f0b
```

I like to throw in the `--ff-only` switch when I expect a fast-forward. It conveys my intent and will also fail *before* doing anything in case my mental model is off.

After the merge, history becomes

```
* 16c6ef4 (HEAD -> feature) Undo incorrect merge; revert to bff23af
*   9a905c0 Merge branch 'develop' into feature
|\
| * 286195b (develop) Change 3
| * 39fc565 Change 2
* | bff23af Feature change 2
* | 8929388 Feature change 1
|/
* 5229c14 Change 1
```

As you can see, we did not rewrite history, so the other commits are still there. This means when you do get the merge right, you will be able to push your feature branch.

Confirm that the trees are the same with

```
git diff 16c6ef4 bff23af
```

No output means no differences. Thinking in terms of how git represents history, you can also confirm they’re the same with

```
$ git rev-parse 16c6ef4^{tree} bff23af^{tree}
d9cc608eedd5d2cc63c262272b7a0f6ab6aed5dd
d9cc608eedd5d2cc63c262272b7a0f6ab6aed5dd
```

What `git rev-parse` does is convert any of the ways you can address a particular Git object into its SHA1 object name. In this case, we asked, “What are the SHA1 object names of the tree objects that commits 16c6ef4 and bff23af refer to, respectively?” Both lines of output being the same means that no only are the contents associated with the two commits the same but that they are in fact *identical*. The later undo commit and the commit immediately prior to the merge now share the same tree.

Of course on *your* repository, the commit messages and SHA1 object names will be different, so substitute the appropriate values on your side to get the result you want.

Comment: Many many thanks, I'm going to have to take some time to digest this :)